# How to access AWS ElastiCache (Redis) from VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, vpn, amazon-elasticache

I have launched an AWS ElastiCache node on AWS VPC. I can access this Redis endpoint from within the VPC resources like EC2.

I have a VPN connection (Virtual Private Network) from On-Premise to this VPC. I can access all other resources like EC2 but, I am unable to access the Redis Endpoint from On-Premise network.

Note: As I am able to access EC2 resources from On-Premise, routing table is set appropriately.

Could you let me know (if I have to modify anything) how to access the Redis Endpoint in VPC from On-Premise network (Without using NAT Instance) (I can use NAT Gateway if required) ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can connect to ElastiCache with redis by using NAT, as [described at the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws).

Alternatively, if you are using simple key/value operations you might want to switch to memcached. With ElastiCache for memcached [you should be able to access from your datacenter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/elasticache-vpc-accessing.html#elasticache-vpc-accessing-data-center), as long as you have configured a Virtual Private Gateway to the same VPC where your ElastiCache is deployed

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to get Redis accessible with your setup. According to AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/VPCs.Connecting.html) you need to create an Ec2 instance in the VPC and use it as a jumpbox to connect to Redis.  I don't like that option either since I can't use the tools I have installed on my developer machine.

I instead (and recommend) you spin up an OpenVPN Remote Access box that is within the VPC, launched into the public subnet, so you can access the Redis cluster.  Just search under community AMI's **OpenVPN Access Server**